# Parsing multiple XML into separate tables in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, parsing, sql-server-2016

I was able to successfully upload the files to the database.
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/FHy6K.png)

I have multiple XML files and I need to parse each one into separate tables according to "Test name".
The first column would contain the "datetime", the second "order id" and the other columns would contain the values of the given "test name".

I have tried googling some instructions but still can't get a good result.

Or is there another easier option e.g. to parse them directly when importing them into the database from the windows folder?

```xml
<eolresult>
  <eolpresetting>
    <datetime>17.02.2022 16:10:37</datetime>
    <order id="16HBOD0222XSK316_FLX101xxxxxxxxxxxxxx000SK35X3PN9P40006C24A4NORL0L7P1XVV0008I06T24D0XVU0006A0LTS000A" />
  </eolpresetting>
  <testresult>IO</testresult>
  <results>
    <!--PRN="16HBOD0222XSK316_FLX101xxxxxxxxxxxxxx000SK35X3PN9P40006C24A4NORL0L7P1XVV0008I06T24D0XVU0006A0LTS000A"-->
    <test name="Time">
      <value name="Time of start ">17.02.2022 16:08:08</value>
      <value name="Time of save ">17.02.2022 16:10:37</value>
      <value name="Time ">149 s</value>
    </test>
    <test name="Manual test">
      <value name="Manual test was used: ">False</value>
    </test>
    <test name="Airbag SAB">
      <value name="Measured value - Generator">2,124602</value>
      <value name="Low limit - Generator">1,74</value>
      <value name="High limit - Generator">2,46</value>
      <value name="Measured value - Break contact 1">5,101295</value>
      <value name="Minumum value - Break contact 1">1,73</value>
      <value name="Measured value - Break contact 2">5,162498</value>
      <value name="Minumum value - Break contact 2">1,73</value>
      <value name="Test OK">True</value>
    </test>
    <test name="Airbag CAB">
      <value name="Measured value - Generator">2,235402</value>
      <value name="Low limit - Generator">1,74</value>
      <value name="High limit - Generator">2,46</value>
      <value name="Measured value - Break contact 1">5,109858</value>
      <value name="Minumum value - Break contact 1">1,73</value>
      <value name="Measured value - Break contact 2">5,12398</value>
      <value name="Minumum value - Break contact 2">1,73</value>
      <value name="Test OK">True</value>
    </test>
    <test name="Heating">
      <value name="Measured value">1,287712</value>
      <value name="Low limit">1,22</value>
      <value name="High limit">1,72</value>
      <value name="Test OK">True</value>
    </test>
    <test name="Thermistor">
      <value name="Measured value">9013,247</value>
      <value name="Low limit">4000</value>
      <value name="High limit">14000</value>
      <value name="Test OK">True</value>
    </test>
    <test name="Buckle">
      <value name="Measured value 1 - unbuckled">9,706554E-02</value>
      <value name="Measured value 2 - buckled">45445,75</value>
      <value name="Measured value 3 - unbuckled">9,584951E-02</value>
      <value name="Bucked limit">3,92</value>
      <value name="Unbuckled limit">999</value>
      <value name="Test OK">True</value>
    </test>
    <test name="SBR">
      <value name="Measured value - Low force">399,4937</value>
      <value name="Low limit - Low force">332</value>
      <value name="High limit - Low force">468</value>
      <value name="Measured value - Low force - Force [kg]">5,334925</value>
      <value name="Low limit - Low force - Force [kg]">5,1</value>
      <value name="High limit - Low force - Force [kg]">6,4</value>
      <value name="Regulator Active - Low force">False</value>
      <value name="Measured value - High force">99,87806</value>
      <value name="Low limit - High force">83</value>
      <value name="High limit - High force">117</value>
      <value name="Measured value - High force - Force [kg]">33,82478</value>
      <value name="Low limit - High force - Force [kg]">33,6</value>
      <value name="High limit - High force - Force [kg]">34,3</value>
      <value name="Regulator Active - High force">True</value>
      <value name="Strain Gauge - Tare [kg]">-10,7119</value>
      <value name="Test OK">True</value>
    </test>
    <test name="Light">
      <value name="Measured value">21,23078</value>
      <value name="Low limit">10</value>
      <value name="High limit">40</value>
      <value name="Test OK">True</value>
    </test>
    <test name="Headrests">
      <value name="Force - Measured">16,30317</value>
      <value name="Force - Low Limit">15,81</value>
      <value name="Force - High Limit">17,64</value>
      <value name="Regulator Active">True</value>
      <value name="Strain Gauge - Tare [kg]">-0,1437721</value>
      <value name="Test OK">True</value>
    </test>
    <test name="ECU test">
      <value name="ECU communication status">Driver seat - Address 36</value>
      <value name="SW version">0560</value>
      <value name="SW version - Verification Active">True</value>
      <value name="SW version - Verification Status">True</value>
      <value name="HW version">010</value>
      <value name="HW version - Verification Active">True</value>
      <value name="HW version - Verification Status">True</value>
      <value name="Part Number">1EA959760H</value>
      <value name="Part Number - Verification Active">True</value>
      <value name="Part Number - Verification Status">True</value>
      <value name="Fazit ID">CNK-SCU27.01.2200010244</value>
      <value name="Coding">01189A00000020500803010101010000000000212100000000000000211000</value>
      <value name="Dataset">DB_036_7100_4M0_2531_SCXXMEBSK31X_1742</value>
      <value name="Dataset position in DAP (ASCII @ #10)">50</value>
      <value name="Initialization Routine 0483041312 IO ECU reply">True</value>
      <value name="Initialization Routine 0533040200 IO ECU reply">True</value>
      <value name="Initialization Routine 0533040300 IO ECU reply">True</value>
      <value name="Initialization Routine 0533041802 IO ECU reply">True</value>
      <value name="Button Forward - Start Position">32876</value>
      <value name="Button Forward - End Position">32854</value>
      <value name="Button Forward - Result">True</value>
      <value name="Button Backward - Start Position">32825</value>
      <value name="Button Backward - End Position">32836</value>
      <value name="Button Backward - Result">True</value>
      <value name="Button Upward - Start Position">32982</value>
      <value name="Button Upward - End Position">32972</value>
      <value name="Button Upward - Result">True</value>
      <value name="Button Downward - Start Position">32942</value>
      <value name="Button Downward - End Position">32973</value>
      <value name="Button Downward - Result">True</value>
      <value name="Button Backrest Forward - Start Position">32499</value>
      <value name="Button Backrest Forward - End Position">32472</value>
      <value name="Button Backrest Forward - Result">True</value>
      <value name="Button Backrest Backward - Start Position">32464</value>
      <value name="Button Backrest Backward - End Position">32490</value>
      <value name="Button Backrest Backward - Result">True</value>
      <value name="Button Thigh Upward - Start Position">32922</value>
      <value name="Button Thigh Upward - End Position">32898</value>
      <value name="Button Thigh Upward - Result">True</value>
      <value name="Button Thigh Downward - Start Position">32872</value>
      <value name="Button Thigh Downward - End Position">32894</value>
      <value name="Button Thigh Downward - Result">True</value>
      <value name="Button Lumbar Forward - Start Position">65216</value>
      <value name="Button Lumbar Forward - End Position">65248</value>
      <value name="Button Lumbar Forward - Result">True</value>
      <value name="Button Lumbar Backward - Start Position">176</value>
      <value name="Button Lumbar Backward - End Position">96</value>
      <value name="Button Lumbar Backward - Result">True</value>
      <value name="Button Lumbar Upward - Start Position">54576</value>
      <value name="Button Lumbar Upward - End Position">54672</value>
      <value name="Button Lumbar Upward - Result">True</value>
      <value name="Button Lumbar Downward - Start Position">55072</value>
      <value name="Button Lumbar Downward - End Position">54896</value>
      <value name="Button Lumbar Downward - Result">True</value>
      <value name="Button SET - Result">True</value>
      <value name="Button 1 - Result">True</value>
      <value name="Button 2 - Result">True</value>
      <value name="Button 3 / Massage - Result">True</value>
      <value name="DTC Deleted">True</value>
      <value name="DTC Record 1" />
      <value name="DTC Record 2" />
      <value name="DTC Record 3" />
      <value name="DTC Record 4" />
      <value name="DTC Record 5" />
      <value name="DTC Record 6" />
      <value name="DTC Record 7" />
      <value name="DTC Record 8" />
      <value name="DTC Record 9" />
      <value name="DTC Record 10" />
      <value name="DTC Flawless">True</value>
      <value name="Test OK">True</value>
    </test>
    <test name="Delivery">
      <value name="Measured value - Backrest">415,7932</value>
      <value name="Low limit - Backrest">410</value>
      <value name="High limit - Backrest">420</value>
      <value name="Measured value - Forwards">468,5211</value>
      <value name="Low limit - Forwards">455</value>
      <value name="High limit - Forwards">475</value>
      <value name="Measured value - Height">1202,52</value>
      <value name="Low limit - Height">1190</value>
      <value name="High limit - Height">1210</value>
      <value name="Measured value - Thigh">1159,799</value>
      <value name="Low limit - Thigh">1130</value>
      <value name="High limit - Thigh">1170</value>
      <value name="Measured value - Headrest">396,1371</value>
      <value name="Low limit - Headrest">320</value>
      <value name="High limit - Headrest">450</value>
      <value name="Delivery OK">True</value>
    </test>
  </results>
</eolresult>
```

I've found some instructions, but I'm still unable to properly specify and modify the query according to my specifications.

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2899/importing-and-processing-data-from-xml-files-into-sql-server-tables/

```sql
USE EOL_Testers
GO

DECLARE @XML AS XML, @hDoc AS INT, @SQL NVARCHAR (MAX)

SELECT @XML = XMLData FROM XMLFilesTable

EXEC sp_xml_preparedocument @hDoc OUTPUT, @XML

SELECT datetime, order id, test
FROM OPENXML(@hDoc, 'eolresult/eolpresetting/results/test')
WITH 
(
datetime [varchar](150) '@datetime',
order id [varchar](150) '@orderid',
datetime [varchar](150) '@datetime'
)

EXEC sp_xml_removedocument @hDoc
GO
```

Comment: FYI, you *really* shouldn't be using those ancient system procedures for consuming XML. SQL Server has supported XQuery since *at least* SQL Server 2005.

Comment: What are your desired results? It doesn't seem like you're querying existing data in the XML document... `@datetime` in conjunction with the path `eolresult/eolpresetting/results/test` is is looking for an attribute named `datetime` on the `test` element.

Comment: Hello I would like to have tables for every <test name=> for example 
**<test name="Airbag SAB"> and another for <test name="Heating">
** and every table also contains datetime and orderid values from 
`<eolresult> 
<eolpresetting> 
<datetime>04.06.2021 15:26:20</datetime> 
<order id="3I6LAKPVSLXSK316_FLX101xxxxxxxxxxxxxx000SK35X3PN9P40006C24A4NORL0L7P1XVV0008I96T24D3ZZF0006A0LTS0000"/> 
</eolpresetting>`

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).
All within the question as text, no images.

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what your intended results are, but you could do something like this

```sql
SELECT
  Date        = x1.presetting.value('(datetime/text())[1]', 'varchar(30)'),
  OrderId     = x1.presetting.value('(order/@id)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
  TestName    = x2.test.value('@name', 'varchar(100)'),
  ValueName   = x3.val.value('@name', 'varchar(100)'),
  ValueResult = x3.val.value('text()[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY t.XMLData.nodes('(eolresult/eolpresetting)[1]') x1(presetting)
CROSS APPLY t.XMLData.nodes('eolresult/results/test') x2(test)
CROSS APPLY x2.test.nodes('value') x3(val);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/JIlZUD4O)

You may want to filter by test name, for example

```sql
CROSS APPLY t.XMLData.nodes('eolresult/results/test[@name = "Airbag SAB"]') x2(test)
```