# MS SQL Parsing xml files to tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, parsing

can you please help me with parsing xml files into tables?
I have in my SQL database thousands of xml files like this:
[image]

These xml files got this structure:

```
`<eolresult>
  <eolpresetting>
    <datetime>08.12.2020 5:24:48</datetime>
    <order id="2049457704XSK316_FRX101xxxxxxxxxxxxxx000SK35X3PH9P40006C24A4NORL0L7P7XYA0000006T24D0XXK0006A00000000" />
  </eolpresetting>
  <testresult>NIO</testresult>
  <results>
    <!--PRN="2049457704XSK316_FRX101xxxxxxxxxxxxxx000SK35X3PH9P40006C24A4NORL0L7P7XYA0000006T24D0XXK0006A00000000"-->
    <test name="Time">
      <value name="Time of start ">08.12.2020 5:23:03</value>
      <value name="Time of save ">08.12.2020 5:24:48</value>
      <value name="Time ">105 s</value>
    </test>
    <test name="Manual test">
      <value name="Manual test was used: ">False</value>
    </test>
    <test name="Airbag SAB">
      <value name="Measured value - Generator">2,111209</value>
      <value name="Low limit - Generator">1,74</value>
      <value name="High limit - Generator">2,26</value>
      <value name="Measured value - Break contact 1">5,069321</value>
      <value name="Minumum value - Break contact 1">1,73</value>
      <value name="Measured value - Break contact 2">5,092026</value>
      <value name="Minumum value - Break contact 2">1,73</value>
      <value name="Test OK">True</value>
    </test>
    <test name="Heating">
      <value name="Measured value">1,294227</value>
      <value name="Low limit">1,22</value>
      <value name="High limit">1,49</value>
      <value name="Test OK">True</value>
    </test>
    <test name="Thermistor">
      <value name="Measured value">8671,408</value>
      <value name="Low limit">4000</value>
      <value name="High limit">14000</value>
      <value name="Test OK">True</value>
    </test>
    <test name="Buckle">
      <value name="Measured value 1 - unbuckled">9,730747E-02</value>
      <value name="Measured value 2 - buckled">25022,52</value>
      <value name="Measured value 3 - unbuckled">8,596408E-02</value>
      <value name="Bucked limit">3,92</value>
      <value name="Unbuckled limit">999</value>
      <value name="Test OK">True</value>
    </test>
    <test name="SBR">
      <value name="Measured value - Low force">99999,9</value>
      <value name="Low limit - Low force">332</value>
      <value name="High limit - Low force">468</value>
      <value name="Measured value - Low force - Force [kg]">5,242241</value>
      <value name="Low limit - Low force - Force [kg]">5,1</value>
      <value name="High limit - Low force - Force [kg]">6,4</value>
      <value name="Regulator Active - Low force">False</value>
      <value name="Measured value - High force">99999,9</value>
      <value name="Low limit - High force">83</value>
      <value name="High limit - High force">117</value>
      <value name="Measured value - High force - Force [kg]">33,80444</value>
      <value name="Low limit - High force - Force [kg]">33,6</value>
      <value name="High limit - High force - Force [kg]">34,3</value>
      <value name="Regulator Active - High force">True</value>
      <value name="Strain Gauge - Tare [kg]">-10,77971</value>
      <value name="Test OK">False</value>
    </test>
    <test name="Light">
      <value name="Measured value">21,33521</value>
      <value name="Low limit">10</value>
      <value name="High limit">40</value>
      <value name="Test OK">True</value>
    </test>
    <test name="Headrests">
      <value name="Force - Measured">16,04999</value>
      <value name="Force - Low Limit">15,81</value>
      <value name="Force - High Limit">17,64</value>
      <value name="Regulator Active">True</value>
      <value name="Strain Gauge - Tare [kg]">-8,725739E-02</value>
      <value name="Test OK">True</value>
    </test>
    <test name="Delivery">
      <value name="Measured value - Backrest">0</value>
      <value name="Low limit - Backrest">0</value>
      <value name="High limit - Backrest">0</value>
      <value name="Measured value - Forwards">0</value>
      <value name="Low limit - Forwards">0</value>
      <value name="High limit - Forwards">0</value>
      <value name="Measured value - Height">0</value>
      <value name="Low limit - Height">0</value>
      <value name="High limit - Height">0</value>
      <value name="Measured value - Thigh">0</value>
      <value name="Low limit - Thigh">0</value>
      <value name="High limit - Thigh">0</value>
      <value name="Measured value - Headrest">384,2014</value>
      <value name="Low limit - Headrest">320</value>
      <value name="High limit - Headrest">450</value>
      <value name="Delivery OK">False</value>
    </test>
  </results>
</eolresult>`
```

And I need to somehowe parse all of these xml files to tables for. example by the "Test name" because I would like to create a report from these data via Power BI. Or if there is some another way how to process these files, I will be glad for every idea.

What I imagine is that the tables would look something like this. Each table contain the ID, the date from the eolpresenting and the values from the tests.
Example:

[image]

Comment: It definitely depends on how data are to be used later. I'd stage it to the `(Datetime, id, testname, valuename, value)` table and dispatched to the proper tables  with a number of pivoting queries and converted string values to the proper SQL types (True/False to bit for example).

Comment: In this case it is enough that all data is in string, I set the data types on the power bi side

Comment: It's interesting how I answered a very similar question two months ago but you entirely ignored it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75927399/parsing-multiple-xml-into-separate-tables-in-mssql

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need a cursor here, you can just use `.nodes` directly in an `INSERT`.

You can even cross-join one set of `.nodes` with another, and you can also pass a single node to `.nodes` to shred a second level.

```sql
INSERT INTO EolResultData
  (DateTime, OrderId, TestName, ValueName, Value)
SELECT
  DateTime = x1.presetting.value('(datetime/text())[1]', 'datetime'),
  OrderId = x1.presetting.value('(order/@id)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
  Testname = x2.test.value('@name', 'nvarchar(100)'),
  ValueName = x3.value.value('@name', 'nvarchar(100)'),
  Value = x3.value.value('text()[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM @XMLData.nodes('eolresult/eolpresetting') x1(presetting)
CROSS APPLY @XMLData.nodes('eolresult/results/test') x2(test)
CROSS APPLY x2.test.nodes('value') x3(value);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/Rn7z907P)

If you are using an actual table with the data, you can change the `FROM` to something like this:

```sql
FROM YourTable t
CROSS APPLY (VALUES( CAST(t.SomeColumn AS xml) )) v(XMLData) -- only necessary if conversion is needed
CROSS APPLY v.XMLData.nodes('eolresult/eolpresetting') x1(presetting)
CROSS APPLY v.XMLData.nodes('eolresult/results/test') x2(test)
CROSS APPLY x2.test.nodes('value') x3(value);
```

This is all the code you need, no cursors necessary. Note the use of `text()` which is more performant than an implicit conversion from `.`

You may want to further transform it into separate tables, for that you can use XQuery predicates, such as this

```sql
SELECT
  DateTime = x1.presetting.value('(datetime/text())[1]', 'datetime'),
  OrderId = x1.presetting.value('(order/@id)[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
  Testname = x2.test.value('@name', 'nvarchar(100)'),
  [Measured value] = x2.test.value('(value[@name="Measured value"]/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
  [Low limit]      = x2.test.value('(value[@name="Low limit"     ]/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
  [High limit]     = x2.test.value('(value[@name="High limit"    ]/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)'),
  [Test OK]        = x2.test.value('(value[@name="Test OK"       ]/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(100)')
FROM @XMLData.nodes('eolresult/eolpresetting') x1(presetting)
CROSS APPLY @XMLData.nodes('eolresult/results/test[@name = "Light"]') x2(test);
```

[**db<>fiddle**](https://dbfiddle.uk/Csy7G4hX)

Comment: Thank you for this solution and I´m sorry for this madness from my side. I´m a newbie on StackOverflow and also in SQL. I've learned from my mistakes and I'll do it by the book next time.

Answer (score -1):

To parse `XML` files and store the data in tables in `MS SQL,` you can use the SQL Server's built-in XML functionality

Write a script or `stored procedure` to parse the `XML` files and insert the data into the tables.

- EolResultData table is included at the beginning
- The XML data is properly declared as an XML variable, @XMLData.
- Cursors are used to iterate through the XML data and extract the required information.

  The nested cursors are structured to process the test and value nodes
  within the XML data.
- The parsed data is inserted into the EolResultData table.

Here is the [template](https://paste.c-net.org/InfiniteUnborn) you can adapt

In the above replace *`YourTableName`* in the `cursor` declaration with the actual table name and column name where your XML files are stored.

This code should parse the `XML files`, extract the required data, and store it in the `EolResultData` table, which has columns for `ID, DateTime, TestName, ValueName, and Value`.

Update:

Assuming  multiple `XML` records are present under the `<eolresults>` element, it  can  handle them correctly without using `cursors` as someone suggested.

The [modified template here](https://paste.c-net.org/HappiestClapping)  uses the `nodes() method` to extract individual `<eolpresetting> nodes` and then performs an `INSERT INTO SELECT` operation to insert the data into the `EolResultData` table. It has the extra `orderId col`

Comment: What's with the cursor? You can just do `INSERT ... SELECT ... FROM @xml.nodes...`